# Moose and extending non moose classes

Tags: perl, inheritance, moose

I have the following class / package:

```
package Data::CrawlerThreadPool;
use Moose;
use MooseX::InsideOut;
use MooseX::NonMoose;

extends 'Thread::Pool::Simple';

around BUILDARGS => sub {
      my $orig  = shift;
      my $class = shift;
      return $class->$orig( do  => [\&_do_handle],
                            min => 5,
                            max => 10 );
};

sub _do_handle {
    $| = 1;
    print "In Do handle";
}
1;
```

in my main script, I call it (for e.g...) like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::CrawlerThreadPool;

my $tp = Data::CrawlerThreadPool->new();
my @args = qw(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0);
$tp->add(@args) for (0..10);
$tp->join();
```

Seems like the BUILDARGS method is called, but the process do handle never being called.
What am I missing here?
[Thread::Pool::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~jwu/Thread-Pool-Simple-0.23/Simple.pm)

thanks,

Comment: Well, you never called `$tp->_do_handle()`, so....what did you expect to happen?

Comment: It looks like Thread::Pool::Simple has a fairly simple API, you would probably be better creating your object to proxy calls to a TPS object it creates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\&_do_handle` is not calling the _do_handle sub - it's just dereferencing a reference to the sub.  This idiom is normally used inside an `eval {}` in order to check that you really have a subref (or an object with a subref overload) -- which I don't think is what you intended to do here.

If you are intending to actually call _do_handle, then call it directly:

```
around BUILDARGS => sub {
      my $orig  = shift;
      my $class = shift;
      return $class->$orig( do  => [ _do_handle() ],
                            min => 5,
                            max => 10 );
};
```

Comment: _do_handle is a callback for Thread::Pool::Simple, calling it like you have mentioned will call it only once, and not for each worker...

Comment: MooseX::InsideOut because Thread::Pool::Simple isnt blessed into a hashref.... or should I check it again, tried several modules... anyway, it doesnt work with MooseX::NonMoose as well

Comment: @soulSurfer2010: well if you want to have something called at a different time than object construction, don't put the call in `BUILDARGS`.

Comment: I want to initialize the TPS module before the construction, so using BUILD is too late... BUILDARGS seems the right tool, isnt it?

Comment: @soulSurfer2010: the point is though that BUILDARGS is called at construction time, and not at any other time. If you need something to be called for every thread creation, for example, you need to move your call somewhere else.

Comment: But thats not the reason Im inheriting from TPS, I want to initialize it without wrapping it inside my own ctor (new)....thats why BUILDARGS returns an hasref, so from then on, my blessed object will act as TPS